# z-index IE issue

Tags: javascript, dom

i m assigning z-index for a div like this,

```
Obj.style.zIndex = "2000";//obj{ position:absolute}
```

FF has no problem with this syntax but IE its not applying this property at all.
how can i achieve same thing in IE.

Comment: can you specify which IE version?

Comment: most of these issues are with IE 6.0 only

Answer (score 1):

I would first check the generated source to see if the property is there and also check what happens if you manually add the property, rather than programatically adding it via Javascript. Could be the property is being set but you are encountering the infamous [IE6 z-index bug](http://mahzeh.org/?p=19)?